# Memory Leak in the below simple code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I have a piece of code & I want to understand the memory leak possibility in this. I have gone through the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)!

The code here process a array from parameter & stores the dictionary into a temporary array.

```
+ (void)setLinkedProfiles:(NSArray *)profileData {
    NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if([profileData count] > 0) {
        for(NSDictionary *dict in profileData) {

            NSDictionary *tempDict = @{
                                   @"verifiedEmail" : ([[dict objectForKey:@"verifiedEmail"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"": [dict objectForKey:@"verifiedEmail"],
                                   @"identifier" : [dict objectForKey:@"identifier"],
                                   };
            [returnArray addObject:tempDict];
        }
    }
    [SharedApp sharedUserData].linkedProfiles = returnArray;
}
```

I suspect that the line of code `SharedApp sharedUserData].linkedProfiles = returnArray` might create a memory leak. 
I want to understand why & in which scenario?
Can some one help me in understanding this ?

Thank you for reading & understanding my problem.

Comment: you declare array like this, NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray array];

Comment: Is ARC enabled in your project?  Does the static analyzer show any warnings?  Does the Leaks instrument show any leaks?

Comment: Yes, Profile analyzer shows for line 
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
"Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count"

and

[SharedApp sharedUserData].linkedProfiles = returnArray;

Object leaked:Object allocated and stored into 'returnArray' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1

Comment: @robmayoff

Here is what I see is that I am sharing. Screen of Profile Analyzer
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/arc-1.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear things up:

Your line

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

gives you ownership of that array. You are responsible to release it when you're done with it.

So adding

```
[returnArray release];
```

as the last line would work. You could use `autorelease` instead, or even work with an autoreleased array from the beginning, i.e.

```
NSMutableArray *returnArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

`linkedProfiles` should be a strong reference (i.e. `strong`, or `copy`).

Although I strongly suggest to switch to ARC, understanding of the underlying memory management might come handy.